# Rotate all pages in a PDF graphics context

Tags: ios, pdf, cgcontext, airprint, cgcontextdrawpdfpage

I'm creating a PDF file containige multiple pages:

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData new];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, rect, nil);
for (NSInteger page = 0; page < 10; page++)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    // DRAW PAGE
}
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

The PDF will be printed, but always in along the longer page side. So at the end and before sending it to a printer, I want to rotate each page by 90°. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage, you can use UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(bounds, dict);
In the dictionary, set a key "Rotate" and value (NSNumber) 90.
EG:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:90] forKey:@"Rotate"];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(bounds, dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by taking one by one page in `UIImage` format and rotate image to 90 degree and then convert image bunch to PDF.